# Getting Date() of Custom Type

Tags: swift

I have a server API that is supplying JSON with dates of two different formats - one structure nested within another.

My Swift app pulling is using Swift Codable to decode the JSON, so I needed to add some special handling to allow the two custom date formats to be decoded.

Handily, I found this [excellent guide](https://blog.usejournal.com/decoding-a-json-having-multiple-date-formats-in-swift-9ad22c443448) to handling different formats within one structure.

```
struct FirstModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int?
    let second: SecondModel
    let date: CustomDate<First>

    ...
}

struct SecondModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int?
    let date: CustomDate<Second>

    ...
}
```

The date formatters are defined as follows,

```
struct CustomDate<E:HasDateFormatter>: Codable {

    let value: Date
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let text = try container.decode(String.self)
        guard let date = E.dateFormatter.date(from: text) else {
            throw CustomDateError.general
        }
        self.value = date
    }
    enum CustomDateError: Error {
        case general
    }
}

struct First: HasDateFormatter {
    static var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: Constants.localeUK)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm zzz"
        return dateFormatter
    }
}

struct Second: HasDateFormatter {
    static var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: Constants.localeUK)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return dateFormatter
    }
}
```

This all works great.

My problem starts when I want to create an object to subsequently encode.

I can't even initialise a struct,

```
let first = FirstModel(id: nil, date: Date())
```

The compiler gives the error,

**Cannot convert value of type 'Date' to expected argument type 'CustomDate' for the 'date' parameter.**

I understand that CustomDate(xxx) is a DateFormatter, so not a Date type, but I don't even know where to start to get a new Date object of that 'type'.  Please could someone help with the syntax for passing in the current date in a way the Swift compiler will accept.  Thanks.

*PS. I also suspect I'm going to need a 'set' encoder at some point, amiright?*

**UPDATE**

Following Joakim's suggested below, plus a suggested Fix from the compiler, I tried,

```
let date = try! CustomDate<First>(from: Date() as! Decoder)
```

...which compiles, but then crashes at runtime, with error,

**Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.Date' to 'Swift.Decoder'.**

Comment: `let first = FirstModel(id: nil, date: CustomDate(value: Date()))`

Comment: Thanks @JoakimDanielson but unfortunately that also doesn't compile.  Compiler error is 'Argument type 'Date' does not conform to expected type 'Decoder'' and 'Incorrect argument label in call (have 'value:', expected 'from:')'

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Since you have implemented an init the synthetic one is no longer created so you need a new init for CustomDate to use when creating objects manually in code.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson No need to apologise, I appreciate the help.  Would that look the same as your initial suggestion in the calling code, but then backed up by an init?

Comment: Yes but you might change the signature if you want but basically an init that takes a `Date` as argument and assigns it to the `value` property

Comment: @JoakimDanielson CustomDate<First>.init(date: Date())  Brilliant!  That worked, and I learned something!  If you want to post that as an answer, I will accept it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LeoDabus If have one date field that is just mm/dd/yy, and another that includes hh:mm:ss.  This linked article describes the same situation.  Alternative suggestions appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: @Snips check my post below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom decoding strategy that can fall back to the second dateFormat in case of failure. If you need to encode your custom structure following the same rule you would need to provide a custom encoding method as well:

First create your DateFormatters

```
extension Formatter {
    static let customUK: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_UK")
        formatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm zzz"
        return formatter
    }()
    static let yyyyMMdd: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_UK")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

Then your custom date decoding strategy

```
extension JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy {
    static let customUK = custom {
        let container = try $0.singleValueContainer()
        let string = try container.decode(String.self)
        guard
            let date = Formatter.customUK.date(from: string) ??
                Formatter.yyyyMMdd.date(from: string) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Invalid date: \(string)")
        }
        return date
    }
}
```

Your custom encoding strategy as well

```
extension JSONEncoder.DateEncodingStrategy {
    static let customUK = custom {
        var container = $1.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(Formatter.customUK.string(from: $0))
    }
}
```

If you need to make sure to encode your sub structure respecting the original date format you will need to provide your own encoding method to it:

```
struct First: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    let second: Second
    let date: Date
    init(id: Int?, date: Date = Date(), second: Second) {
        self.id = id
        self.date = date
        self.second = second
    }
}
```

---

```
struct Second: Decodable {
    var id: Int?
    let date: Date
    init(id: Int?, date: Date = Date()) {
        self.id = id
        self.date = date
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Second: Encodable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(Formatter.yyyyMMdd.string(for: date), forKey: .date)
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let first = First(id: 1, second: .init(id: 2))
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .customUK
let data = try! encoder.encode(first)

print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!) // {"id":1,"second":{"id":2,"date":"2020-06-02"},"date":"Tue, 2 Jun 2020 16:31 GMT-3"}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .customUK
let firstDecoded = try! decoder.decode(First.self, from: data)
print(firstDecoded)  // "First(id: Optional(1), second: __lldb_expr_227.Second(id: Optional(2), date: 2020-06-02 03:00:00 +0000), date: 2020-06-02 19:38:00 +0000)\n"
```